# Changing X axis scale in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a X-Y scatter plot, my values in the x axis starts from the value 30.

How can i change the scale in the chart in such a way that I have values in the X axis starting from 30 and not zero?

Comment: This question is better suited to Super User as it is not programming related. I have voted to migrate it

Comment: I want to do programmatically..I have an empty chart, and i have a macro which populates the graph on the empty chart..

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this in VBA as follows:

1. grab the chart object:

   ```
   Dim objChart As Object
   Set objChart = Sheets("MyWorksheetName").ChartObjects("MyChartName")
   ```
2. change the x-axis min value:

   ```
   objChart.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = myChartMinXValue
   ```

The x-axis in Excel charts seem to be called `xlCategory`. Also NOTE the `MinimumScale` property doesn't exist for all chart types. My first attempt was using `xlLine` but I kept getting an error. Once I switched to `xlXYScatterLines` VBA was happy.

Answer (score 1):

- right click the x-axis
- select `Format Axis`
- select the `Fixed` option next to `Minimum` and enter 30